# Can you use `pgfplotstable` to do a linear regression to an expression?

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I have a lot of data in a table, but it is not linearly related. I can linearize the relationship by computing functions (`x expr` and `y expr` expressions). I would like to use `pgfplots` to show the results of the data expressions in a pgfplot and use the `create col/linear regression` operation to find and plot the regression line.

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
    \pgfplotstableread{%
     myx myy
     1 1
     2 1.41
     3 1.67
     4 2.03
     5 2.2
     6 2.45
     9 2.97
}\mytable

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xlabel=my x,ylabel=(my y)$^2$]
    \addplot[only marks] table {\mytable}; %
    \addplot[only marks] table[y expr=\thisrow{myy}*\thisrow{myy}] {\mytable};    
    \addplot[no marks] table[y={create col/linear regression={y=myy}}] {\mytable}; %

%    \addplot[no marks] table[y={create col/linear regression={y expr={\thisrow{myy}*\thisrow{myy}}}}] {\mytable};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here's the output:
[image]

I have plotted both `myx vs myy` and `myx vs myy$^2$` data points, and the linear regression of the raw data.  When I try to do a linear regression on the square of `myy` I get errors. The specific errors depend on the form of the `[y={create col/linear regression={....}}]` statement that I try, and I have tried many which don't work.

Is it possible to do this regression in the `pgfplots/pgfplotstable` context? If not, short of inputting the linearized data points, what will do it, because I already have the data table in LaTeX ...

(And WHY doesn't this SE section support MathJax input?!)

Comment: Regarding MathJAX you might want to read this: [Why doesn't maths render as maths?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1272/why-doesnt-maths-render-as-maths)

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks. Interesting history of the issue.

Comment: I looked through the `pgfplotstable.sty` and the associated `pgfplotstable.code.tex` to see if I could understand what is happening with `create col/linear regression`. Sadly, I'm not conversant at the level of that code (yet). I couldn't find any `expr` keys or hooks in those files.  I'm hoping someone is busily implementing this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after digging around I found functions to create a new column in the table. After doing that, I can do the linear regression on the newly calculated (linearized) column.  This may not be the most efficient or elegant code to create the column, but it works.

I'm using `\pgfplotstableset{create on use ...}` to calculate a new column `myysquare` which is then the `{y=myysquare}` value in the regression. My actual linearizing operation for the real data is only slightly more complicated, so porting this shouldn't be a problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
    \pgfplotstableread{%
     myx myy
     1 1
     2 1.41
     3 1.67
     4 2.03
     5 2.2
     6 2.45
     9 2.97
}\mytable
\pgfplotstableset{ %
    create on use/myysquare/.style={ %
         create col/expr={\thisrow{myy}*\thisrow{myy}}}
         }
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xlabel=my x,ylabel=(my y)$^2$]
    \addplot[only marks] table {\mytable}; %
    \addplot[only marks] table[y=myysquare] {\mytable};    
    \addplot[no marks] table[y={create col/linear regression={y=myy}}] {\mytable}; %

    \addplot[no marks] table[y={create col/linear regression={y=myysquare}}] {\mytable}; %
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Sorry for the huge image.  I had to use `pdftoppm` to convert the pdf to a png (the Markdown control wouldn't load a pdf, and I'm unfamiliar with UBUNTU image tools...moving from a Windows environment). It converted the whole stinkin' page.  I'd appreciate any clue about cropping the page, either an app or in `pdftoppm`.